# Testing an H2 positioning

Tags: css, cross-browser, position, styles, html-heading

I was wondering if someone could look at hawkeyeelectronics.com and help me figure out why a certain h2 title is positioned incorrectly in some Chrome/Firefox/IE browsers of the same version but not others.

Background: I changed the layout of this site's homepage so that the heading "PRODUCTS, SERVICE & SUPPORT... THE HAWKEYE® WAY!" (an H2) wouldn't be overlapping the "FEATURED DEPTH FINDERS AND FISH FINDERS" (an H1) text at the top of the page.

On my browser and my manager's browser (both Chrome Version 50.0.2661.75 m (64-bit)) and on my browser at home it looks fine. But one other coworker and, apparently, the rest of the world still sees the H2 and the H1 overlapping! It's a bit difficult to troubleshoot from my computer because the problem doesn't exist in any browser I try (Chrome/IE/Firefox/Safari).

Here's the correct layout

[correct layout](https://i.stack.imgur.com/k34pe.png)

Here's the incorrect layout

[incorrect layout](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tGeJb.png)

Maybe a kind person here can try this URL and a) see if it has the layout problem and b) offer advice for what can be done.

Thanks.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Questions seeking code help must include the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself**.   Although you have provided a [**link to an example or site**](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/254428/something-in-my-web-site-or-project-doesnt-work-can-i-just-paste-a-link-to-it), if the link were to become invalid, your question would be of no value to other future SO users with the same problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This bug occurs only when your browser window is too small. When it's 1200px wide, everything is fine.

You should fix the use of your bootstrap grid, it seems to be mixed up.

Comment: Thanks. That is indeed the threshold for when the H2 jumps up and overlaps the H1. For some reason it never occurred to me to do the resizing. This is currently a "quick fix" patching effort. The bootstrap you're seeing replaces an earlier table layout which was not working well as tables are for data, not layouts. I haven't had the opportunity to update the entire page to be Bootstrap.